# What does '()' mean in the Delphi Debugger?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe5

The value '()' keeps coming up whenever I inspect or watch an expression in the Delphi debugger.

What does it mean ? And if it represents an object of some kind, how can I visualize that object's state ?

Comment: Any chance of some detail. Give us an example of such an expression.

Comment: Going into inspect usually helps. If the type information is uncertain you may need to typecast it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can mean two different things, depending on whether you're looking at an array or an object.

For an array, it means you have an array (usually a dynamic array) containing 0 elements.

For an object, it's a bit more complicated.  It means that you're examining an object that's *declared as* a type that does not contain any data members.  If you're looking at a variable that's declared as `TObject` in the code (such as a `Sender: TObject` in an event handler), the actual type is almost certainly not `TObject`, but the debugger will evaluate it as the type it's declared as.

To get actual data about the object, do this:

- Pull up Evaluate/Modify (Ctrl-F7).
- Evaluate the object's real type.  (`Sender.classtype`)
- Evaluate the object, cast to its real type. (`TMyObject(Sender)`).  This will tell you what the object actually contains.

Comment: It is a shame that the debugger is not smart enough to automatically extract an object's class type and inspect it as that actual type.